# Increment of Alphanumeric 6.A.1

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have these location ids 6.A.1 in column "D20" and wants to increase it as 6.A.2 And so on  until
it reaches 6.A.6, THEN 6.B.1 , UNTIL it reaches 6.B.6

Comment: And when it gets to `6.Z.6` where does it go?

Comment: It finishes at 6.z.6

Comment: also it would be appreatiated if we have the way to put any other location once it ends on 6.Z.6 Foe example 7.A.1 AND then increase to 7.A.2, and so on this is just an option though. Thanks in advance for looking into it really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
M1:  6.A.1
M2:  =CONCATENATE(LEFT($M$1,FIND(".",$M$1)-1),".",CHAR(MOD(INT(ROWS($1:1)/6),26)+ CODE(MID($M$1,FIND(".",$M$1)+1,1))),".",RIGHT($M$1)+MOD(ROWS($1:1),6))
```

*and fill down*

Answer (score 0):

You may try this formula `=(INT(ROW(A156)/156)+5)&"."&(CHAR(MOD(INT(ROW(A6)/6)-1,26)+65))&"."&(MOD(ROW()-2,6)+1)`in **D20** or **D21**, then fill down to check the result.

[image]